# Validating Username And Password from MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm looking for a code that validates the username and password in VB.

```
Private Sub LoginBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn.Click
    Try
        con.Open()
        com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE uname='" & txtuname.Text & "'", con)
        reader = com.ExecuteReader
        If reader.HasRows = True Then
            com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE pword = '" & txtpword.Text & "' AND uname='" & txtuname.Text & "'", con)
            If reader.HasRows = True Then
                Form3.Show()
            Else
                MsgBox("Invalid Password")
                txtpword.Focus()
            End If

        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtuname.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Username")
            txtuname.Focus()
        Else
            MsgBox("New User Detected. Input Password")
            Form2.Show()
        End If

        reader.Close()
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Close()
        End If
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

The conditions goes like this:

1. If the username is not detected from the dbase, it'll lead to a registration form(which is form2)
2. If the username was detected but the password is wrong or empty, a msgbox will pop up
3. If the username and password is both correct, it'll lead to form 3.

My problem is condition #2. Even though the data in the pword txtbox is wrong, it still keeps leading to form 3 instead of showing a msgbox.

Comment: For security issues, I would not make a separated case when the user does not exists and when the password is wrong. It is better to make only two cases: success or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to call again

```
reader = com.ExecuteReader
```

After:

```
com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE pword = '" & txtpword.Text & "' AND uname='" & txtuname.Text & "'", con)
```

You have just checked it has rows before and you have not changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `reader = com.ExecuteReader` after second query ie. after

```
com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE pword = '" & txtpword.Text & "' AND uname='" & txtuname.Text & "'", con)
```

Due to which it considers the output for the first query only and second query remains unexecuted

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the reader again or it won't execute the second query. As the others have suggested. With that, your code seems to be for a public application. With code written this way, you are leaving yourself vulnerable to injection attacks. A user may insert malicious code into your textboxes and the server could process it. It would be better if you use parameters in your queries versus .Text of textboxes, like this:

```
    Private Sub LoginBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn.Click
Try
    con.Open()
    com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE uname=@uname, con)
    With com
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtuname.Text)
    End With
    reader = com.ExecuteReader
    If reader.HasRows = True Then
        com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE pword = @pword AND uname = @uname, con)
    With com
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", txtuname.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pword", txtpword.Text)
    End With
    reader = com.ExecuteReader

    If reader.HasRows = True Then
            Form3.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid Password")
            txtpword.Focus()
        End If

    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtuname.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid Username")
        txtuname.Focus()
    Else
        MsgBox("New User Detected. Input Password")
        Form2.Show()
    End If

    reader.Close()
    con.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Close()
    End If
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
     End Sub
```