# Retrieving Data from MySQL using VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Newbie here! I'd like to retrieve data from the table I made in MySQL for my Visual Basic. Been looking for ways to do one but sadly, I still cant figure out how it works. The process goes like this:
1. Login form window is shown
2. After clicking the Login button, It'll determine whether the account is a user or an admin by retrieving data from the DB
3. It'll open another form in which it depends whether the account is an admin or not (so there's 2 login forms that I made. One for the user and one for the admin)

Here's what I've done so far. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
 Private Sub LoginBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn.Click
    Try
        con.Open()
        com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE uname='" & txtuname.Text & "'", con)
        reader = com.ExecuteReader
        If reader.HasRows = True Then
            reader.Close()
            com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE pword = '" & txtpword.Text & "'", con)
            reader = com.ExecuteReader
            If reader.HasRows = True Then
                reader.Close()
                com = New MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE account_type = '" & account_type & "'", con)
                reader = com.ExecuteReader
            ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpword.Text) Then
                MsgBox("Invalid Password")
                txtpword.Focus()
            Else
                MsgBox("Invalid Password")
                txtpword.Focus()
            End If

        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtuname.Text) Then
            MsgBox("Invalid Username")
            txtuname.Focus()
        Else
            MsgBox("New User Detected. Input Password")
            Form2.Show()
        End If
        reader.Close()
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Close()
        End If
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating Username And Password from MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924700/validating-username-and-password-from-mysql)

Comment: Well it is. That's the question I posted earlier.